# Create array in class (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Edited...
I have my constructors for class foo

```
foo();
foo(int);
foo(const foo&);
```

How do I dynamically allocate/initialize int number of arrays of foo using the constructor
`foo(int)`;

The aim is to call `foo(int)` and be able to access array using in main.cpp `foo[int]`
as `foo[1], foo[2]...`

Without using `vector`...

Comment: You can't. The size of *C arrays* must be defined at compile time.

Comment: So you want to make your own vector class?

Comment: why is this tagged C++?

Comment: This is inconsistent, title says C++, but file name is C. Which is it, it matters

Comment: you write c++ code,you ask about C,and you name the file `main.c`??

Comment: If this is about C++ dynamic arrays, I suggest you do some research before posting. Very simple and basic stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a private data member in the Foo class that is a pointer, such as `int* arr`, in the constructor you dynamically allocate it to an array of certain type like this:

```
foo::foo(int size)
{
    arr = new int[size];
}
```

Comment: Better to use initialization syntax whenever it's available, and it is in this case.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo{
    public:
    Foo(int num){
        max = num;
        arr = new int[num];
    }

    ~Foo(){
        delete [] arr;
     }

    //overloading of operator []
    int &operator[](int i){
        int re = 0;
        if(i < max)
            return arr[i];
        else
            return arr[0];
    }


    private:
        //pointer to an array
        int *arr;
        //size of an array
        int max;
};

//simple example
int main()
{
    Foo foo(10);
    foo[5] = 5;
    std::cout << foo[5] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit lazy...
    Foo::~Foo(){ delete [] arr; }
Implement the rest by yourself

Comment: @0x35 thanks, Your code has improved my understanding of what I'm trying to do...  would this be work if I have foo X(2) and access X[0], X[1]...?

Comment: A class that allocates memory without a destructor must leak. You can leave it to the OP to implement the rest, but then you should say so in the answer. (Note that I am not the OP.)

Answer (score -2):

```
struct foo_class
{
    foo_class(int i) : arr(new something[i]) {}

    something const& operator[](int i) const { return arr[i]; }

private:
    boost::scoped_array<something> arr;
};
```

If you don't use boost then it's easy enough to make a scoped_array template class.